# use ffmpeg to extract video frames with time code specified on the SRT file

Tags: ffmpeg

Complete newbie on ffmpeg here. I have a video file and an SRT subtitle file. Is there any way I can have ffmpeg read the time code on the SRT and use that as an input parameter for ffmepg to specify exactly when to extract video frames?

If this is too complex for ffmpeg, are there other approaches you can recommend to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thank you guys in advance for your input.

Allen

Comment: Not with `ffmpeg` by itself as far as I know. You'll have to parse the SRT file with your preferred tools then provide the info to `ffmpeg`. I don't know your OS/shell/language so I can't give any specific suggestions other than that.

Comment: Thank you llogan for your advice. Appreciate it!